# Jenkins: Can we checkout the submodules with user defined branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-submodules

I have a peculiar requirement, I need to change the branch name of the submodule which is mentioned in the `.gitmodule` file.
ex:
consider below is my `.gitmodule`  file.

```
[submodule "submodule"]     
   path = aiml/core/model/modelcollection   
   url = ssh://git@git.myorg.com/project/repo.git   
   branch = module1
```

I am using Jenkins checkout function as below.

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: 'develop']],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
        disableSubmodules: false,
        parentCredentials: true,
        recursiveSubmodules: true,
        reference: '',
        trackingSubmodules: false]
        ], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "git@git.myorg.com/project/repo.git"]]
])
```

My case: I need to change the branch name which is already mentioned in `.gitmodule` (i.e module1) to a different branch name example "module2". Is this possible while using the Jenkins checkout function?
Is there any other way to fulfil the above requirement?

Note: Just a curious add on the question. Can we add two entries in `.gitmodule` and clone only one based on the need. Is this possible with Jenkins checkout.

Comment: As far as I know this is not supported in normal command line git operations, so I would not expect it to be in Jenkins either. If it is possible, you should be able to find it in the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/)

Comment: Worth thinking about: Git itself doesn't even check out submodules by default. You have to run `git submodule update`. You can turn on recursive checkout, but that means you get a lot of defaults. If you want control, (1) don't turn on recursive checkout and (2) don't use the defaults when you run `git submodule`. (How to make Jenkins do that, I have no idea. I hate Jenkins with a passion.)

Comment: @fredrik @torek is there any way to update only one submodule out of all the entries in ```.gitmodule``` file